# How to draw a graph of sounds while recording in java sound?

Tags: java, javasound

I successfully recording java sounds from my micro phone and can draw the recorded wave file 
graph as in attached image.
(I have tried to upload image from here a lot, but it is failed every time.i also used tinypic also but failed in uploading , i think there is some error in my internet connection, i will upload it later here. )

I am also attaching all my code.
http://pastebin.com/EgW2ZcyJ

Now, my question is i want to display Graphs for the sound while recording in real time .so if i try to read audio input stream which is used in recording in new thread and sleep this thread for 1 seconds until the recording is finished . but in this approach it gives frame length -1 so nothing can be drawn.

**so how can i draw a graph means how can i get frames of recorded sound [bytes from audio input stream] while recording in real time , so i can use it to draw a graph using it in different thread so i can exactly simulate what window's sound recorder provides ??**

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Comment: I won't follow the link to 'all your code'.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513)  uses [`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) to display recent changes to a time-based series.

> Sorry, but you don't understand my question.

Addedndum: You can edit your question to clarify; this will also help guide future answers. In the interim, you might be able to adapt [`TeeOutputStream`](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Streams/WritingIOSC/index.html) to intercept the `OutputStream` from `AudioSystem.write()`.

[image]

Comment: I think Mr. trashgod did not understand my question yet. i am not looking for how to draw a graph , i am looking for first how to retrieve recorded bytes simultaneously which is in audio input stream being filled from target data line i choose and from those bytes i will draw a graph.so drawing graph is not an issue here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with the `com.actura.app.capture` API.

Comment: did you see the link ? it is very simple . i am concern with only run method of that class . once i get bytes from that i can draw the graph in real time of captured voice.

Comment: Yes, I saw the link. What method? What bytes? The `appendData()` method in the example accepts an array of bytes.

Comment: sorry but you don't understand my question.